# How to optimize jquery datatable to load large data efficiently (10k-50k rows)?

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I am using jquery datatable with minimal configuration to showcase data on my website. I have **10K to 50K records to show in datatable**.

Currently the datatable is taking around **60 seconds to initialize 3000 records**.

**There are two options that can be utilized to initialize data-table:-**

1) Add records as a html table on page and then initialize datatable on that table.
2) Have a json of records and then initialize datatable with that data.

**Do the following steps helps us to improve the performance of datatable plugin:-**

1) Reducing number of columns
2) Grouping related columns
3) Using sort only on required fields or remove sort feature all together

**Data is as follows**
 - It is a set of mcq questions with options to preview/edit/delete

[image]

**Search on question is something very important for my application**. 
Please provide an optimal solution to use datatable for the provided dataset.

Comment: you're never going to optimize that to be very efficient. It's just not possible.

Comment: Then should i switch to some other plugin or solution.

Comment: can i know which database you are using ? because jquery data table will pass in which page you are in , how many pages per page using that we can optimize the database query hitting

Answer (score 9):

You forgot a third option: server side processing

You can learn almost everything you need to know from the official documentation:
http://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html

Basically what you do is you only load data that is absolutely required to display the table. As the page needs more data such as going to a different page or searching, the server returns the client with more data.

> There are many ways to get your data into DataTables, and if you are working with seriously large databases, you might want to consider using the server-side options that DataTables provides. With server-side processing enabled, all paging, **searching**, ordering etc actions that DataTables performs are handed off to a server where an SQL engine (or similar) can perform these actions on the large data set (after all, that's what the database engine is designed for!). As such, each draw of the table will result in a new Ajax request being made to get the required data.

Comment: server side processing is a definite solution, but my doubt is to have a best possible solution for the front-end as current data-set 3000 rows are taking that much time. So i thought of learning a good front end solution

Comment: @abhinsit Relying on the client for heavy processing is never a good idea. The client might not have enough processing power to do the computation. You also do not want to waste bandwidth by sending unnecessary data through the network. In any case, any JavaScript/JQuery solution designed to handle UI will never be as fast as a SQL database that is designed to handle large datasets. DataTables IMO is the best JQuery table library out there in terms of features and ease of use. You might be able to find other libraries out there but you are going to lose features such as search and sorting.

Comment: @abhinsit Just want to add one more reason for server-side processing: as I noticed, you are using custom cells rendering, I mean, last 3 columns have buttons, so that issue really slow down your UI, especially in old versions of IE. I came across this when trying to render particular columns of a table with additional links inside cells on a set of 2k records (in IE8 I got a alert proposing to stop script execution)

Comment: @ChernikovP Also I suggest that he rework the UI. Having buttons for CRUD operations on every row is kind of redundant. A better way to accomplish this is to just have those buttons at the top of the page. When you click on a certain row, that row is highlighted and you can select what operation to perform using the same set of buttons at the top.